# Issue with Vixen Seq - Pi3 - FPP- relay board

Tags: pi-3, gpio, relay

I'm trying to wire my Pi 3B to the relay (octocoupler). I'm wiring the 5V (pin 2 and 4 on the Pi) to the relay, also the grounds. I'm using the following GPIOs from the Pi (Pin numbers): 7(GPIO4)-11(17)-13(27)-15(22)-29(5)-31(6)-33(13)-35(19)-37(26)-40(21)-38(20)-36(16)-32(12)-22(25)-18(24)-16(23).

I use the test page, but the relay is not being triggered. The start channel matches the numbers of each pin in the relay, I thought it was because the relay is powered with 12V with a charger.

Below are some pics

[[image: GPIO pinning I'm working with[1]]

[image: Pins Configuration on FPP]

[image: Vixen setup]

[image: 16-Channel board I have]